# How to update an array in mongodb by using another array as both identifier and value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Imagine the is a document like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID('someIdblahbla')
  users: [
    {
      _id: 'id1',
      name: 'name1',
    },
    {
      _id: 'id2',
      name: 'name2',
    },
    {
      _id: 'id3',
      name: 'name3'
    }
  ]
}
```

I have an array like this:

```
const newData = [
  {_id: 'id1', name: 'newName1'},
  {_id: 'id2', 'name': 'newName2', family:'newFamily2'}
]
```

what I want is to update the array in the document using the corresponding `_id` and using it to add/update each element.
so my end result would be like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID('someIdblahbla')
  users: [
    {
      _id: 'id1',
      name: 'newName1',
    },
    {
      _id: 'id2',
      name: 'newName2',
      family:'newFamily2'
    },
    {
      _id: 'id3',
      name: 'name3'
    }
  ]
}
```

my guess was using [The filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#mongodb-update-up.---identifier--)  but I am not sure if it's the correct way to go and how to do it.

thank you for your kind tips beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to add/update in array, you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

First of all, you need to convert `_id` from string to objectId type, if you are using mongoose npm you can use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` method or if you are using mongodb npm you can use `ObjectId` method,

```
let newData = [
  { _id: 'id1', name: 'newName1' },
  { _id: 'id2', 'name': 'newName2', family:'newFamily2' }
];
let newIds = [];
newData = newData.map(n => {
  n._id = ObjectId(n._id); // or mongoose.Types.ObjectId(n._id)
  newIds.push(n._id); // for checking conditions
  return n;
});
```

You can put query condition, and do below operations,

- `$map` to iterate loop of users array, check condition if `user._id` is in input `newIds` then do update operation otherwise do insert operation
- update operation:

  - `$filter` to iterate loop of input `newData` and filter already present object from input so we can update it
  - `$arrayElemAt` to get first object from above filtered array
  - `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with above input object
- insert operation:

  - `$filter` to iterate loop of `newData` array and return not present object means new items in array of objects
- `$concatArrays` to concat above new and updated result array

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { _id: ObjectId("someIdblahbla") },
  [{
    $set: {
      users: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$users",
              as: "u",
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $in: ["$$u._id", newIds] },
                  {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$u",
                      {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                          {
                            $filter: {
                              input: newData,
                              cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$u._id"] }
                            }
                          },
                          0
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$u"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $filter: {
              input: newData,
              cond: { $not: { $in: ["$$this._id", "$users._id"] } }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qaSpXGCswiI)

Comment: Is this still working? I am trying this on a project of mine and I am getting errors... Could you take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188663/mongoose-update-add-elements-from-an-array-and-other-properties-in-a-single-quer?noredirect=1#comment136076681_77188663

Answer (score 0):

**Query1** (update(merge objects) existing members, doesn't add new members)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PQPZA0vLJhS)

Replace

- `[{"_id": "id1","name": "newName1"},{"_id": "id2","name": "newName2","family": "newFamily2"}]` with you array or the driver variable that hold the array

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$eq": "1"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "users": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$users",
          "as": "user",
          "in": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": [
                {
                  "_id": "id1",
                  "name": "newName1"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "id2",
                  "name": "newName2",
                  "family": "newFamily2"
                }
              ],
              "initialValue": "$$user",
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "old_user": "$$value",
                    "new_user": "$$this"
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$$old_user._id",
                          "$$new_user._id"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$mergeObjects": [
                          "$$old_user",
                          "$$new_user"
                        ]
                      },
                      "$$old_user"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Query2** (update(merge) if found, else push in the end)
Its like the above but finds the not-existing members,and push them in the end.Its a bit more slower and complicated

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OpJ6DQC7Nt4)

Replace

- `[{"_id": "id1","name": "newName1"},{"_id": "id2","name": "newName2","family": "newFamily2"},{"_id": "id4","name": "newName4"}]`
  with your array or the driver variable that hold the array

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$eq": "1"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "yourarray": [
        {
          "_id": "id1",
          "name": "newName1"
        },
        {
          "_id": "id2",
          "name": "newName2",
          "family": "newFamily2"
        },
        {
          "_id": "id4",
          "name": "newName4"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "new-ids": {
        "$setDifference": [
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$yourarray",
              "as": "u",
              "in": "$$u._id"
            }
          },
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$users",
              "as": "u",
              "in": "$$u._id"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "users": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$users",
              "as": "user",
              "in": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$yourarray",
                  "initialValue": "$$user",
                  "in": {
                    "$let": {
                      "vars": {
                        "old_user": "$$value",
                        "new_user": "$$this"
                      },
                      "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                          {
                            "$eq": [
                              "$$old_user._id",
                              "$$new_user._id"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "$mergeObjects": [
                              "$$old_user",
                              "$$new_user"
                            ]
                          },
                          "$$old_user"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$yourarray",
              "as": "u",
              "cond": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$u._id",
                  "$new-ids"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "yourarray",
      "new-ids"
    ]
  }
])
```