# Can I edit multiple documents from an array of them in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, express

well...

I have a collection of users, one user looks like

```
{ userId: "someId", fullName: "AnyName", email: "anyEmail@mail.com"}
```

and of course Mongo adds one `_id`

all fine here, but a have an express server and I receive and array of existing users with a POST.

```
[ 
   { userId: "123", fullName: "name1 EDITED", email: "anyEmail1@mail.com"},
   { userId: "124", fullName: "name2 EDITED", email: "anyEmail2@mail.com"},
   { userId: "125", fullName: "name3 EDITED", email: "anyEmail3@mail.com"},
   { userId: "126", fullName: "name4 EDITED", email: "anyEmail4@mail.com"}
]
```

I want edit the existing user with the news values receive in the array but I don't know if I have to iterate and update each document or if I can pass the array of users to update all of them with a single query.

similar to what `"insertMany"` method does

Comment: i think you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876736/how-to-update-an-array-in-mongodb-by-using-another-array-as-both-identifier-and/68878181#68878181) , its possible with pipeline update and 1 query

Comment: check the UpdateMany coomand: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/